# How to set background transparency and color to VerticalFieldManager and/or HorizontalFieldManager?

Tags: java, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

The following code isn't working, I would appreciate some help.

```java
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
hfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **0** as alpha value on `createSolidTransparentBackground(int color, int alpha)`.

It will create a fully transparent background (not visible). Check the range of the alpha value in documentation.

[It says](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BackgroundFactory.html#createSolidTransparentBackground%28int,%20int%29), **alpha - 0 (clear) to 255 (opaque)**. Try other values for alpha, e.g. **127**.